# Why does this program allocate more space on the stack than required?

Tags: x86, stack, 32-bit, buffer-overflow

I am currently playing the [picoCTF 2018](https://2018game.picoctf.com/game) challenges. Level "buffer overflow 1" gives you the followng source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include "asm.h"

#define BUFSIZE 32
#define FLAGSIZE 64

void win() {
  char buf[FLAGSIZE];
  FILE *f = fopen("flag.txt","r");
  if (f == NULL) {
    printf("Flag File is Missing. Problem is Misconfigured, please contact an Admin if you are running this on the shell server.\n");
    exit(0);
  }

  fgets(buf,FLAGSIZE,f);
  printf(buf);
}

void vuln(){
  char buf[BUFSIZE];
  gets(buf);

  printf("Okay, time to return... Fingers Crossed... Jumping to 0x%x\n", get_return_address());
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){

  setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);

  gid_t gid = getegid();
  setresgid(gid, gid, gid);

  puts("Please enter your string: ");
  vuln();
  return 0;
}
```

So exploit the `gets()` in `vuln()` to overwrite the return adress and jump to `win()`. Since `buf` has a size of 32, I was expecting the stack to look like this:

```
|-------------------|
|        ...        |
|        buf        |
|        buf        |
|        buf        |
|        buf        |
|-------------------|
|     saved ebp     |
|-------------------|
| return after vuln |
|-------------------|
|        ...        |
|-------------------|
```

So I attempted to input 36 random characters and then the return adress, which did not work. Using gdb I found out that the stack actually looks like this:

```
|-------------------|
|        ...        |
|        buf        |
|        buf        |
|        buf        |
|        buf        |
|-------------------|
|        ???        |
|        ???        |
|-------------------|
|     saved ebp     |
|-------------------|
| return after vuln |
|-------------------|
|        ...        |
|-------------------|
```

There are 8 bytes between the end of `buf` and the saved ebp. My question is: What are these 8 bytes for?

Comment: By my knowledge this should be how the stack looks like (with ASLR etc. disabled of course). [Layout](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Call-stack-layout.svg)

Comment: I would find it helpful if you could give me constructive feedback instead of "obviously" answers. These kinds of beginner challenges normally have compiler optimizations and protection disabled to make it easy. So I assume the two words contain something I don't know about.

Comment: Which compiler with what options did you / they use to compile that source?  It's well known that gcc doesn't always pack locals on the stack optimally, and even when it doesn't waste space for no apparent reason, the i386 System V ABI requires it to align the stack by 16 before a `call`.  And the ABI also requires 16-byte alignment for local arrays.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no information about the compiler and options used.

Comment: @4386427 You only get the compiled binary and source code for each challenge. The point is you have ssh access to the machine running the binary.